# how to fix when i use dig SERVFAIL id:40642 on BIND

Tags: debian, bind

i try to make DNS but when i use

```
**DIG lantern.com**
```

it return **status:SERVFAIL** 
but when i use

```
**nslookup lantern.com**
or **nslookup 192.168.1.2**
```

it work and when i check in

> nano /etc/resolv.conf

```
search lantern.com
nameserver 192.168.1.2
```

how can i fix this ??